# WPF Window with Control in Full Screen Mode

Tags: wpf, controls, fullscreen

I have a WPF window hosting a web browser control. I want this WPF window to always be on top. Now for example user surfs to a Youtube page and the web player plays a video. User clicks on the full screen button in the Youtube player and the video fills the screen. But my WPF window that hosts web browser control now is still on top of everything and it looks weird because in the background, the video plays fullscreen.

Is there any way an embedded control can tell WPF window that it's in fullscreen mode now so that the WPF is no longer on top, say maybe hidden?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with `Topmost` property. If you display content not in `Popup` than this should works:

```
window.Topmost = false;
```

Comment: But how in the first place can my WPF window know when the control goes into fullscreen mode?

Comment: @user1058058 I beleive that web browser and flash player use the Win32 API to go to fullscreen mode. So, it could be difficult to catch this event. Not sure about how to do this.